# Why is my LPvariable type is not respected in pulp?

Tags: python, pulp

I am working on an optimization problem using pulp in python. One of my constraints is a list of binary. To do so, I set a list called `lpvar_list`, and I append my variables inside it:

```
lpvar_list.append(pulp.LpVariable(f"binary i={i} year={t}",cat='Binary'))
```

However, the result doesn't give me a binary. What might be the reason `pulp` would ignore my type settings?

Comment: please provide simple working code example

Comment: Without seeing any more code, my guess would be that your problem is infeasible. Print the status of your problem after solving to check - `pulp.LpStatus[prob.status]`